# Plotting a 2D list of co ordinates to a 2D map

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, coordinates

This is my attempt at mapping a set of co-ordinates in a 2d list to a 2d map. Each co ordinate is given as(y,x) y and x representing the given axis on the map. the map is simply a grid of 0's, the position of the co ordinate should be marked with a "1"

[image: My code]

Here is my output and my expected output, im not sure why the pattern is repeating, how can i get the expected output for any given co-ordinates?

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

to initialise a 2d array use this instead of your code:

```py
map = [ [0]*5 for i in range(5)]
```

otherwise all the lines will be the same.

also PLEASE DON'T TAKE PICTURES OF CODE.

Comment: Thanks alot, this problem made me give up on my larger project several times, i can finally finish it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value:

```
a = [[0]]*10
print(a)
a[0][0]=10
print(a)
b = [[0] for _ in range(10)]
print(b)
b[0][0]=10
print(b)
```

In the first case (how you initialize the list) Python is lazy and instead of creating N copies of the same thing, it creates the object (let's call it LST) once and passes its reference N times to your list, meaning modifying any of the N copies, results in a modification to LST, which in turn shows up as a modification to all N "copies".
In the second case, you tell python that no, don't be lazy and actually create N copies (pass-by-value) for me since I want to modify them.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, thank you for the excellent explanation!